# svg elements being clipped

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

[image: Snip 1]

[image: Snip 2]

[image: Snip 3]

Does anyone know why the behavior displayed in the above images might be occurring? In the first image, the x and y coordinates of the svgArcs container are set to zero so the center is in the top left corner and only the bottom right corner is displayed, as expected. In the second image, I moved the container, but still only the bottom right corner is displayed. I posted the document structure so maybe you can take a look and tell me what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

By default `<svg>` elements [clip](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#OverflowAndClipProperties) their contents.

You could specify overflow="visible" on them or alternatively (and better) use a `<g>` element as a container rather than an `<svg>` element. You'll still need to keep the outermost SVG element an `<svg>` element.

Comment: This is what I originally had but when I positioned the containers using transform they didn't line up even though I was using the exact same values. Would you know a way to fix this?

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question on that point and provide complete markup.

Comment: It's the exact same markup just with the "svgImages" and "svgArcs" svgs changed to g containers. I'm then also obviously positioning them with transform instead of x and y. Edit: I'm actually getting the same issue doing it your way (which did fix the clipping issue so thank you) so I'll post a new question as per your suggestion.

Comment: @user3649110 Feel free to accept the answer (click on the tick mark till it turns solid green) if it helped.